# Laravel can't acess Postgres database

Tags: php, database, postgresql, laravel

I need a help to connect Laravel with PostgreSQL database in Linux (ElementaryOS based on ubuntu 14.04)

I already installed the php-pgsql driver and restarted the apache2 and postgresql services.

This is my php.ini:

```
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

This is the query:

```
$usuario = DB::select('select * from usuario');
```

Error in laravel:

"could not find driver (SQL: select * from usuario)"

My .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=minha_db
DB_USERNAME=meu_user 
DB_PASSWORD=minha_senh3
```

database.php

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'minha_db'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'meu_user'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'minha_senha'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

Comment: Configuration looks fine. Did u restart your server?

Comment: Are you sure you edited the right `php.ini`?  Try <?php phpinfo(); ?> and check.

Comment: @MahaDev Yes, I did, I restart my computer too and not working yet.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I going to try to print phpinfo and I' ll post the result

Comment: @Don'tPanic I run the php.ini and it said that Postgre support are enable

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I've solved it using:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```

Before I've installed the package without specification the version using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pgsql
```